# How to add back accidentally deleted pod files that are residing inside the pod folder?

Tags: xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I am new to Firebase for iOS mobile development.

As I was configuring pod file into my Xcode workspace. I have accidentally deleted the files inside the pod folder as I was prompted in the terminal that the files needs recovery.

Can I know how to install the files back?

Comment: Have you tried running `pod install` again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-run `pod install` and things should be back to normal :)

Comment: Hi sir, I just did. however, my terminal hanged. can i know if there is any other alternate way? sorry I am new to xcode and so is swift. merci :)

Comment: @milke  I am able to `pod install